# Unable to figure runtime error in below code

Tags: java

Hi iam unable to figure runtime error in below problem, Please can anyone resolve

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution6 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean condition = false;
        do
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String value = scanner.nextLine();
            condition = value.equalsIgnoreCase("exit");
            if(!condition && value.contains(","))
            {
                calculate(value);
            }
        } while (!condition);
    }

    private static void calculate(String value)
    {
        final String[] event1 = value.split(",");
        int ss = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < event1[0].length(); ++i )
        {
            char c = event1[0].charAt( i );
            ss += (int) c;
        }
        int sd = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < event1[1].length(); ++i )
        {
            char c = event1[1].charAt( i );
            sd += (int) c;
        }

        System.out.println(ss-sd);
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get the Exception ?

Comment: when try it in eclipse its not giving any exception, i have put this code in online exam site, there the site will complie it, after compiling it say runtime error, but not providing which line or exception name

Comment: So try it out on your computer, it will tell you on what line the Exception occured. We need more details about the problem, so we can help you.

Comment: hey i tried it on my machine which have eclipse, it not given any exception and providing output also

Comment: The class must be `public`. Maybe that's the problem. But the compiler should've complained about that...

Comment: Why the class be public?

Comment: @sans481 Because it will probably be the only class in its file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if the user provides an input with a comma (`,`) and the comma is the last character (or the only character), then `event1` will have at most 1 element: `event1[0]`. The element `event1[1]` will not exist, so you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This only happens if the input is like this: `bgh,`, `afsfgf,` or even `,`.

You can solve this by checking the number of elements that the array `event1` contains.